# How can I read parent nodes with partly selected child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree

I'm using dynaTree http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/index.html in my code to show a 2 level tree. this tree is shown in `selectMode = 3` with `checkboxes` and when user check a node checkbox, its parent turns to `gray mode`.

in next stage when user clicks a button I'm sending all selected nodes to server to process. 
What I would like to do is send all `gray mode` check boxes as well.

How can I achieve this goal?

Edit:
This is all the code you need

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/ui.dynatree.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dynatree.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var treeData = [
            { key: "key1", title: "Text 1" },
            { key: "Key2", title: "Text 2",
                children: [
                    { key: "Key2_1", title: "Text 2_1" },
                    { key: "Key2_2", title: "Text 2_2" },
                ]
            },
        ];

        $(function () {
            $("#tree").dynatree({
                checkbox: true,
                selectMode: 3,
                children: treeData,
                imagePath: "../images/Tree/",
                onSelect: function (select, node) {
                    var selKeys = $.map(node.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function (node) {
                        return node.data.key;
                    });
                    $('#textField').val(selKeys.join(", "));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree"></div>
    <input type="text" id="textField" value="" /><input type="button" id="button" onclick="alert($('#textField').val())" value="Send" />
</body>
</html>
```

When selecting `Key2_1`, `Key2` goes to `gray state` and you'll see `Key2_1` is added to `textField` text box, I would like to have Key2 in `textField` field too.

Note: selecting both child nodes of `Key2_1` and `Key2_2` will also select the parent (key_2) but not when it is in `gray mode`

Comment: Please post the code that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems dynaTree does not have a method to look for partially selected nodes. 
An alternative solution is to look for class names of such nodes. by default if the class name for partially selected nodes is not changed, it will be `dynatree-partsel`, however a node with fully selected children has that class assigned too so we need to select nodes that does not have `dynatree-selected` in their classes.

A dirty solution will be change onSelect method definition to :

```
onSelect: function (select, node) {
    var selKeys = $.map(node.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function (node) {
        return node.data.key;
    });
    var partsel = new Array();
    $(".dynatree-partsel:not(.dynatree-selected)").each(function () {
        var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(this);
        partsel.push(node.data.key);
    });
    selKeys = selKeys.concat(partsel);
    $('#textField').val(selKeys.join(", "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = node.getParent();
var parentnode = parent.data.key;
```

in the `parentnode` variable you will get the parent node's value

Comment: Please read the requirement carefully! I need to find the nodes with partial sub-nodes selected.