# Create TreeView from existing TreeView's checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

I'm trying to create a "dynamic useraccess" to specific nodes in an existing dynamic treeview.

The main TreeView contains checkboxes and is populated from a database.
I have a second table in the database where the useraccess to this TreeView is stored.

The problem is when i'm trying to set the useraccess there is no "3-state checkboxes" in the main treeview and the Ref-ID for some Nodes will not be part of the postback. I'm using the javascript:

[Treeview in web form check child nodes on parent node check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157869/treeview-in-web-form-check-child-nodes-on-parent-node-check)

I cannot build an new treeview from the data in the postback due to the lack of the Parent Node (Ref-Node) that is not part of the postback.

The highlighted treeview image below display the problem, when unchecking cabinet 2, room 2 is unchecked but so are Location 1 and Demotop. The Reference Node to Room1 (Location 1) is not part of the checked checkboxes and then the reference in the database is lost! 
Any sugestions on how to solve this?

[[image]
[[image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a Dynatree instead of using treeview.

with support from this:
[How can I read parent nodes with partly selected child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827216/how-can-i-read-parent-nodes-with-partly-selected-child-nodes)

This code solved my problem:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#tree").dynatree({
            checkbox: true,
            selectMode: 3,
            onSelect: function (select, node) {
                var selKeys = $.map(node.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function (node) {
                    return node.data.key;
                });
                var partsel = new Array();
                $(".dynatree-partsel:not(.dynatree-selected)").each(function () {
                    var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(this);
                    partsel.push(node.data.key);
                });

                selKeys = selKeys.concat(partsel);                 
            },
            onClick: function (node, event) {

                if (node.getEventTargetType(event) == "title")
                    node.toggleSelect();
            },
            onDblClick: function (node, event) {
                node.toggleSelect();
            },
            onKeydown: function (node, event) {
                if (event.which == 32) {
                    node.toggleSelect();
                    return false;
                }
            }           
        });
    });
```